# How to iterate a value within a function from 1 to 20 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run the following code:

`sixandinfirst6_df = df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == 1)]`

`sixandinfirst6_df = df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == 2)]`

`sixandinfirst6_df = df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == 3)]`

... and so on until:

`sixandinfirst6_df = df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == 20)]`

What's the best way to do this with no copy pasting? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
mask=(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6) & (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull())
df_mask= df[mask]
for i, group in df_mask.groupby('over'):
    print(group)
    sixandinfirst6_df=group
```

Also you can create a dictinoary of DataFrames and 
and access it based on the `over` value:

```
df_over={i:group for i, group in df_mask.groupby('over')}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of simplicity, I will re-write the operation as a function:

```
def func(df, x):
  return df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == x)]
```

Now to apply it easily to a range, and get all the desired values out of it, you can use list comprehension. Given that df is already defined in the following execution, all you have to do is:

```
all_values_from_1_to_20 = [func(df,x) for x in range(1,21)]
```

range generates a sequence from [x,y), being x the lower boundary, and y the high boundary, to have 20 inside the high boundary, you need to pass 21 as the high boundary is not inclusive.

Comment: this in practice is much slower than the use of groupby

Comment: I wasn't too much concerned about performance as the question is mostly around iterating over data in python. I wanted to present a more broad way to do so, not a framework-related way, this will be way more helpful than just showing a new function of the framework that might not be useful in his next problem

Comment: the correct way to iterate over python data specifically in dataframe and in this case is to use groupby. I think performance is always important.

Comment: There's always more than one way to iterate data, and all possible solutions have pros/cons. I will not follow up into this discussion as I don't think this will give us any fruits.

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval() to run strings as code:

```
for i in Range(1, 21): eval(
        "sixandinfirst6_df = df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift(1)==6)& (~df['player_dismissed'].notnull()) & (df['over'] == {})]".format(i))
```